# Apache and custom HTTP method

Tags: apache-2.2, http-method

Is it possible to make apache accept custom HTTP methods? Say I want to send `DESCRIBE` method.

I tried enabling it in Limit directive but apache returned 405 method not allowed.

Here is my config, it's in `mod_userdir`.

```
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
        <Limit GET POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS DESCRIBE>
              Order allow,deny
              Allow from all
        </Limit>
        <LimitExcept GET POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS DESCRIBE>
              Order deny,allow
              Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
   </Directory>
```

I enabled `PUT` and `DELETE` methods in that config also, as default configuration does not allow `PUT` and `DELETE`.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do something like that? Even if you can massage Apache into accepting it (I'm not sure you can, since Apache is designed to be a HTTP server), no user agent is going to speak your custom method anyway. If instead you describe your *goal*, maybe someone can propose an actual solution.

Comment: Why I want that? Just fooling around :). Also I know that custom extension to http is "bad", I meant this only for personal project, or rather I say, test.

Comment: Also HTTP specification does not forbid implementation of custom methods.

Comment: This made me laugh. Sounds like something I'd find myself doing in my spare time too though. In fact that's how I ended up on this page ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You'd have to write a module to accept the custom method. [Mod_dav](http://www.webdav.org/mod_dav/) might be a good place to start; I don't know of any others that extend Apache's methods.

Comment: Oh didn't think about that, thanks for tip. It's definetly worth a try, if just for a heck of it.